# Apache - (104)Connection reset by peer: [client x.x.x.x:4712] AH03308: ap_proxy_transfer_between_connections: error on sock - ap_get_brigade

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app deployed to elastic beanstalk:

http://django-env.eba-bcvm9cxz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/chart/

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@elspanishgeek/how-to-deploy-django-channels-2-x-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-8621771d4ff0 and using architecture number 2.

My relevant configuration files are the folllowing:

```
option_settings:  
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: dashboard.settings
    PYTHONPATH: /opt/python/current/app/dashboard:$PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: dashboard/wsgi.py

  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elbv2:listener:5000:
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: HTTP
```

--

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      ProxyPass /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ upgrade=NONE
      ProxyPassReverse /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
```

I needed to add `upgrade=NONE` in proxy.conf, which isn't in the tutorial, because I always got a 503 on the client when it was establishing the websocket.

I have a daphne server listening on 5000, which is successfuly receiving the websocket request from the client, but the client never gets to receive the response from the server. On chrome console I get:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://django-env.eba-bcvm9cxz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/websockets/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 408
```

On daphne's command line I get:

```
2020-06-29 08:25:00,770 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=5000:interface=\:\:
2020-06-29 08:25:00,770 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2020-06-29 08:25:00,770 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=5000:interface=\:\:
2020-06-29 08:25:00,772 INFO     Listening on TCP address :::5000
::ffff:127.0.0.1:51162 - - [29/Jun/2020:08:25:11] "WSCONNECTING /websockets/" - -
connected {'type': 'websocket.connect'}
::ffff:127.0.0.1:51162 - - [29/Jun/2020:08:25:11] "WSCONNECT /websockets/" - -
{"mode": "historical", "data": {"funding": [], "index": []}}
::ffff:127.0.0.1:51162 - - [29/Jun/2020:08:26:02] "WSDISCONNECT /websockets/" - -
disconnected {'type': 'websocket.disconnect', 'code': 1006}
2020-06-29 08:26:12,834 WARNING  Application instance <Task pending coro=<SessionMiddlewareInstance.__call__() running at /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:183> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f9dc6fd3738>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['::ffff:127.0.0.1', 51162] path=b'/websockets/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

Apache's logs show the following:

```
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701448 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22730] mod_authz_core.c(844): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701482 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy.c(1255): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH01143: Running scheme ws handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701501 2020] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_ajp.c(743): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH00894: declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701505 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1021): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH01076: url: ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701509 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1024): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH01077: declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701514 2020] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_http.c(1962): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701518 2020] [proxy_scgi:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_scgi.c(538): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH00865: declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701522 2020] [:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_uwsgi.c(459): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] declining URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701525 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 22730] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(321): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH02451: serving URL ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701548 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(2338): AH00942: WS: has acquired connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701553 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(2393): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH00944: connecting ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ to 127.0.0.1:5000
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701618 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(2616): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH00947: connected /websockets/ to 127.0.0.1:5000
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701673 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(3085): AH02824: WS: connection established with 127.0.0.1:5000 (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701695 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(3269): AH00962: WS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:5000 (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701722 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(164): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701725 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 27 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701729 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): GET /websockets/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701732 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 22 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701735 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Host: 127.0.0.1:5000\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701738 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 32 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701740 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701743 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 42 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701746 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701749 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 25 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701752 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701754 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 84 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701757 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Cookie: csrftoken=UVFIJnnTJunPo48gIlzMWY5faRUG9OrLG6fSbIuyv5GishtoB8J2e91UkZmLLqka\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701760 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 71 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701763 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Origin: http://django-env.eba-bcvm9cxz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701766 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 18 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701769 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Pragma: no-cache\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701771 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 70 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701774 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701777 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 45 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701780 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Sec-WebSocket-Key: C0LIw5FM5I76j0+RCx5mwQ==\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701783 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 27 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701785 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701788 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 129 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701795 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701799 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 46 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701801 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): X-Forwarded-For: 78.130.85.107, 172.31.14.21\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701804 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 22 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701807 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): X-Forwarded-Port: 80\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701810 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 25 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701812 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): X-Forwarded-Proto: http\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701815 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 74 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701818 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): X-Forwarded-Host: django-env.eba-bcvm9cxz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701821 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 64 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701824 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): X-Forwarded-Server: ip-172-31-6-170.us-west-2.compute.internal\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701827 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): 43 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701829 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-POOL): Upgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\n\r\n
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.701832 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814047 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(140): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-nonblocking] 8192 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814092 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 207 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814101 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nServer: Daphne\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: Ks+j/i0WQXD2tPynVBYHdjRIvk4=\r\n\r\n\x81<{"mode": "historical", "data": {"funding": [], "index": []}}
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814112 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814115 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): 207 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814118 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nServer: Daphne\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: Ks+j/i0WQXD2tPynVBYHdjRIvk4=\r\n\r\n\x81<{"mode": "historical", "data": {"funding": [], "index": []}}
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:10.814142 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(140): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-nonblocking] 8192 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:32.113745 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 6 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:32.113750 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): \x89\x04qxs1
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838076 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 22860] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838251 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838342 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838425 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22860 for (127.0.0.1) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838486 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838545 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838605 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22860 for (*) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838661 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(1935): AH00924: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:38.838712 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22860] proxy_util.c(1992): AH00926: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.226547 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22726] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.14.21:52506] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.226638 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22789] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.14.21:52504] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.839826 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 22866] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.839973 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840067 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840150 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22866 for (127.0.0.1) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840211 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840270 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840329 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22866 for (*) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840384 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(1935): AH00924: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:42.840435 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22866] proxy_util.c(1992): AH00926: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.306531 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.44.122:13292] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.306572 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(151): [client 172.31.44.122:13292] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70014
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.306580 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.44.122:13292] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.306584 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.44.122:13292] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.306588 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.44.122:13292] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOC): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.841737 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 22872] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.841930 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842498 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842550 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22872 for (127.0.0.1) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842563 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842568 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842577 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22872 for (*) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842581 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(1935): AH00924: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:43.842584 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22872] proxy_util.c(1992): AH00926: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:47.663940 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22728] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.14.21:52528] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:47.663982 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22728] mod_dumpio.c(151): [client 172.31.14.21:52528] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70014
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:47.663990 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22728] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.14.21:52528] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:47.663994 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22728] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52528] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:47.664008 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22728] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52528] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOC): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126484 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(140): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-nonblocking] 8192 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126540 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 6 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126545 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): \x89\x04VWSS
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126555 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126559 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): 6 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126562 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): \x89\x04VWSS
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126565 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52464] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:52.126589 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(140): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-nonblocking] 8192 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:53.306843 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22860] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.44.122:13298] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:53.306894 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22860] mod_dumpio.c(151): [client 172.31.44.122:13298] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70014
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:53.306905 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22860] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.44.122:13298] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:53.306909 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22860] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.44.122:13298] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:53.306913 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22860] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.44.122:13298] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOC): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.771440 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22866] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.44.122:13244] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850330 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 22881] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850485 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850563 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850651 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22881 for (127.0.0.1) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850716 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(1940): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850770 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(2000): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850840 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00930: initialized pool in child 22881 for (*) min=0 max=4 smax=4
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850907 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(1935): AH00924: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ shared already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:54.850959 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22881] proxy_util.c(1992): AH00926: worker ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/ local already initialized
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:57.663678 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(140): [client 172.31.14.21:52538] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:57.663718 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(151): [client 172.31.14.21:52538] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 70014
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:57.663727 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 172.31.14.21:52538] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:57.663745 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52538] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-FLUSH): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:53:57.663749 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22795] mod_dumpio.c(63): [client 172.31.14.21:52538] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (metadata-EOC): 0 bytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:54:02.019865 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(140): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in [readbytes-nonblocking] 8192 readbytes
[Mon Jun 29 08:54:02.019906 2020] [dumpio:trace7] [pid 22730] mod_dumpio.c(151): [remote 127.0.0.1:5000] mod_dumpio: dumpio_in - 104
[Mon Jun 29 08:54:02.019911 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(4059): (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 172.31.14.21:52464] AH03308: ap_proxy_transfer_between_connections: error on sock - ap_get_brigade
[Mon Jun 29 08:54:02.019927 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 22730] proxy_util.c(2353): AH00943: WS: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the load balancer from my application and changed my config files to:

01_env.config

```
option_settings:  
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: dashboard.settings
    PYTHONPATH: /opt/python/current/app/dashboard:$PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: dashboard/wsgi.py

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:http:
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:websocket:
    Port: '5000'
    Protocol: HTTP
```

03_proxy.config

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      ProxyPass /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
      ProxyPassReverse /websockets/ ws://127.0.0.1:5000/websockets/
```

For some reason the load balancer wasn't letting the response from daphne pass through to the client.